# Git Command - not recognizing ls command

Tags: windows, git

I am using Udacity to learn programming but I am having problems.

I am able to locate the file I want at `C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text.exe` but anytime I try to use Git command line to find it it tells me No such file or directory exists.

I have uploaded pictures[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYKB0.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeFb9.jpg) showing where it shows the file in the directory and it telling me that no such directory exists.

Comment: הסתדרת? אם לא נעזור לך בשמחה

Answer (score 1):

You are on windows, if you have spaces you need to use quotes
 `ls "C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text.exe"`